# jquery validation submitbutton not working after corrected validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

When using the jQuery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate):

I want the following behavior: Validate as soon as the user presses submit (instead of actually submitting I am using an ajax post request).

What happens though is the following: As soon as submit is pressed, validation runs, I get a validation error when applicable, then when I correct the mistake, and press submit the form gets re-validated, but when there are no validation errors, the ajax post is not made, only the form gets validated.

When there are no validation errors in first instance, the post is made instantly, like it should.

I have the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#form").validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                onsubmit: true,
                rules: {
                    telNR: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        minlength: 10
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    telNR: {
                        required: "Fill in a valid telephone NR",
                        minlength: "A telephoneNR is 10 characters long",
                        digits: "Use only numerics"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    var jqxhr = $.post("sendMail.php", { telNR: $("#telNR").val() },
                    function(data) {
                        alert("Done");
                    })
                    .error(function(jqXHR){
                        alert("Error");
                    });
                }    
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having some ghost validation errors.  Try adding the following to your options to cleanup the errors on focus of the form:

```
focusCleanup: true
```